# Retrieving data and passing to textview

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I'm trying to think of the logic behind how I should do this. The way I am doing it right now is sort of a hack, but it works. It's just too many API requests and unnecessary, so hopefully someone here can help me envision on how I should do this.

I'm using the parse.com SDK for android to retrieve data to display videos.

Here is my code for the video function

```
int count = 9;


private void getVideos()
  {

       ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Videos");
       query.whereEqualTo("videoid", count);
       query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
           public void done(List<ParseObject> videoData, ParseException e) {
               if (e == null) {
                   /** check to see if there are any more videos **/
                   if(videoData.size() == 0){
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No more videos found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }else{
                     for(int i=0; i<videoData.size(); i++){
                          String videoUrl = videoData.get(i).getString("url");
                          String videoTitle = videoData.get(i).getString("title");
                          String videoUser =  videoData.get(i).getString("user");

                          TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.videoTitle);
                          title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                          title.setText(videoTitle);

                          TextView user = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.videoUser);
                          user.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                          user.setText("By: " + videoUser);

                          myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
                          myVideoView.setVideoPath(vineVideoUrl); 
                          myVideoView.setMediaController(null);
                          myVideoView.start();

                          /** loop video **/
                          myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                myVideoView.start();  

                             }
                          });

                            /** next video **/
                           Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                           button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                   count++;
                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   getVideos();
                               }
                           });

                       }

                   }
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve videos, please check back later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       });


  }
```

Each time the button is pressed, it increments count, and gets the video for that ID from the API. What I am trying to figure out is how can I retrieve say the latest 20 videos from the API the correct way?

The way I can think the proper way to do it is this:

Get latest 20 videos from API, store in array, then when button is pressed loop thru each. How would I pass them each to the textview? And how should I know when it's the last video (20) and to call the API again and pass back the new results?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List<String> oldMovies` which will hold the ids of the movies you already received, now each time you want bring more movies in your query add this constraint `movieQuery.notConteindIn("onjectId", oldMovies)`. That shall return a list of movies that doesn't have one of the `objectsId` contained in the `oldMovies`. Each time you will need to update the `oldMovie` list of ids.